# Android Facebook share: activity not found

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity

I have problem with my function for posting data on Facebook:

```
    public void postData() {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
        i.setType("text/*");
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://sample_url.com");
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("http://sample_url.com));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Every time I get information that activity com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity can't be run and I should add code to the Android manifest. Facebook application is installed on the phone.

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Exception in LogCat:

```
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3531)
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3283)
01-30 14:46:00.903: E/AndroidRuntime(11626):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3370)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 10):

Finally I got this code to work:

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text...");
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
        startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Main points are `setPackage` and `setType` - now Android chooses right activity from Facebook package.

Comment: @nickfox, could you describe what is not work and what you see in console?

Comment: the text box in the facebook app is not populated. See this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Answer (score 1):

for all of those who are using appcelerator here how got it to work...

```
var intFB = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                       action : Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
                        packageName : "com.facebook.katana",                        
                        type : "text/plain"
                    });                    
                    intFB.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com");
                    //facebook only supports LINKS(!!!)
                    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intFB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...you should declare `com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This should do.

**Edit:**

O o ... problem lies in `setClassName` method. Replace your following line

```
  i.setClassName("com.facebook.katana","com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
```

with this one:

```
   i.setClassName("com.facebook.katana","ShareLinkActivity");
```

As second parameter in the method is `className` and you were also passing package name with the class name which the debugger was unable to find. As class name is `ShareLinkActivity` **not** `com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity`.

This will finally solve your problem.

Comment: It's declared - problem is still present.

Comment: Also it didn't help... I replaced setClassName for a setPackage (with different arguments ofc) and it's work now. Anyway, thanks for helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

Just so we are all on the same page with this. Facebook has intentionally broken this and refuses to fix it and shame on them for doing so.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423